# Will disconnecting the battery lock out my stock car stereo in my 2006 Mazda 3?

Tags: mazda-3

I remember there was a time that stock radios we programmed with an anti-theft logic in such a way that if they lost the power source, they will automatically lock out requiring an unlocking code from the dealer.

I need to do some work on my 2006 Mazda 3, and for that, I need to unplug the battery. My concern, and thus question is: if doing so, will it lock out the stock stereo? and thus require me getting an unlocking code from the Mazda dealer.

Answer (score 0):

You should have the code, usually in the handbook for the car or on a metallic or plastic tag.

If it has been lost then either you can get a "code saver" which plugs into the cigar lighter and stops the radio loosing its code - warning this does **not** work on all models - do check.

Or, you can go to the dealership and they can, either for free or a small (usually) fee sort the correct code for you.

There are some people advertising the same service on the www, but be careful... some are good others...

Comment: The vehicles for which the "code saver" are unlikely to work are those which do not have a live convenience outlet when the key is off.

Comment: @fred_dot_u have one permanent live and one switched on my car - factory done, just make sure you know which is which...

Comment: Good point. I realize now that my aft compartment has a live-always outlet, while the dash version is key based.